# Meu modal fecha, mas não popula campos do form chamador

Tags: javascript, asp

Tenho postado algumas dúvidas aqui sobre `ASP` e `js`. Recebi muita ajuda do colega TobyMosque e também do Maicon. Bem, com a ajuda de ambos e do código que o Toby me passou, consegui evoluir bastante aqui na substituição do `ASP` pelo `js`, e claro nosso objetivo, fazer funcionar o `Modal` no `Chrome`. Bem, acontece que o último formulário estou tendo problemas com ele. Ele sobe de forma Modal, fecha corretamente(um dos problemas do Modal no Chrome), mas os campos no formulário chamador continuam vazios, não populados. Fiz muitas tentativas e a que vou postar foi a última no momento. Passe o dia de hoje todo e não consegui nada para terminar a tarefa. Ainda tenho bastante dúvidas a respeito e não creio ser do `ASP`, mas sim do `js` em como substituir. O problema todo está no `ELSE` do primeiro `IF(ASP)`. Abaixo o código original e em seguida, o que eu fiz para substituir.

```
function selecionar(codigo, descricao)
    {

        <% If Request("grid") <> "" Then %>

            <% If modal= "S" then%>
                 if (window.dialogArguments) // Internet Explorer supports window.dialogArguments
                    { 
                        var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
                    } 
                    else // Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome and Opera supports window.opener
                    {      
                            var oMyObject = parent.window.opener;
                    }  

                var oGrid = oMyObject.document.all["<%=grid%>"].object;
            <% Else %>

                var oGrid   = window.opener.document.all["<%=grid%>"].object;
            <% End If%>
            <%If col_cod <> "" Then %>
                oGrid.setCell(<%=linha%>,'<%=col_cod%>',codigo);
            <% End If %>
            <%If col_nom <> "" Then %>
                oGrid.setCell(<%=linha%>,'<%=col_nom%>',descricao);
            <% End If %>

        <% Else  %>

            var txt_retorno = '';

            <%if txtfuncao <> "" then%>
                try{
                    txt_retorno = 'window.<%=txtfuncao%>;';
                }catch(e){
                    txt_retorno = '';
                }
            <%end if%>


            try{

                window.parent.opener.document.form01.<%=codcampodisplay%>.focus();
            }catch(e){}


   if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer"){
            //if (bowser.msie){
                window.returnValue = 'window.document.form01.<%=codcampodisplay%>.value="' + codigo + '";' + 'window.document.form01.<%=nomcampodisplay%>.value="' + descricao + '";' + txt_retorno;
                window.parent.close();
            }else{
                window.parent.opener.document.form01.<%=codcampodisplay%>.value = codigo;
                window.parent.opener.document.form01.<%=nomcampodisplay%>.value= descricao;
                try{
                    window.parent.opener.document.form01.num_cnes_solicitante.focus();
                } catch (e) {}
                window.parent.close();
            }

        <% end if %>
    }
```

Abaixo uma das muitas tentativas que fiz e não deu certo.

```
var asp    = {};
            asp.grid   = '<%= Request("grid")%>';
            asp.linha  = "<%= linha%>";
            asp.colcod = "<%= col_cod%>";
            asp.colnom = "<%= col_nom%>";
            asp.txtfuncao = "<%= txtfuncao%>";
            asp.codcampodisplay = "<%=codcampodisplay%>";

        function selecionar(codigo, descricao) {

            var janela = window.dialogArguments || window.parent.opener || window.parent.dialogArguments;

            if (janela) {
                var form01 = null;

                if (janela.document) {
                    form01 = janela.document.form01;
                }
                else {
                    form01 = janela.elements;
                }

                var container = form01 || janela.document.opener;//isso tá errado


                if (asp.grid != "") {

                    var oGrid = grid;

                    if (asp.colcod != "")
                        oGrid.setCell(asp.linha, asp.colcod, codigo);
                    if (asp.colnom != "")
                        oGrid.setCell(asp.linha, asp.colnom, descricao);

                } else {
                    var txt_retorno = '';
                    txt_retorno = asp.txtfuncao != "" ? window.asp.txtfuncao : "";

                    try{

                        window.parent.opener.document.form01.asp.codcampodisplay.focus();
                    }catch(e){}

                    if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer"){
                        //if (bowser.msie){
                        window.returnValue = 'window.document.form01.<%=codcampodisplay%>.value="' + codigo + '";' + 'window.document.form01.<%=nomcampodisplay%>.value="' + descricao + '";' + txt_retorno;
                        window.parent.close();
                    }else{
                        container[form01 + asp.codcampodisplay] = codigo;
                        container[form01 + asp.nomcampodisplay] = descricao;
                        try{
                            window.parent.opener.document.form01.num_cnes_solicitante.focus();
                        } catch (e) {}
                        window.parent.close();
                    }

                }

            }//janela

            try {
                window.parent.dialogWindow.close();
                //janela.close();
            }
            catch (e) {
                parent.self.close();
            }

            //parent.self.close();

        }
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda para encontrar o caminho das pedras.

Está dando esse erro, mas procurei uma chave não fechada, um parêntesis não fechado e etc e não vejo nada:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Minha dificuldade está em carregar a variável, usando o mesmo princípio que o Toby me passou assim:

```
window.parent.opener.document.form01.<%=codcampodisplay%>.value = codigo;
```

e aqui

```
window.returnValue = 'window.document.form01.<%=codcampodisplay%>.value="' + codigo + '";' + 'window.document.form01.<%=nomcampodisplay%>.value="' + descricao + '";' + txt_retorno;
```

Comment: olha, não acho que precise detectar o IE neste caso, o codigo escrito para os demais browsers deve funcionar no IE tambem, no caso seria apenas `container[asp.codcampodisplay].value = codigo;`

Comment: você não precisa fazer todo este rodeio com `var form01...`, tente apenas atribuir `var container = janela.document.form01;`

Comment: @TobyMosque, poste seu comentário como resposta para eu aceitar. Deu certo.